# Adobe encore - Highlight button with image

Tags: adobe, encore

My question is simple, is it possible to add images as highlights to buttons with Adobe Encore?

I have just tried it and it appears a white box instead of my image when I hover buttons in my DVD menu. I've been searching around and didn't find any solution. Found some people with the same problem but I don't find anywhere a solution for this problem.

I did my menu in Photoshop as named the image layer as `(=1) Hightlight` so it would appear when I hover buttons and appears the white box instead of the image.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it may be some kind of a processing glitch.  Menus don't actually do an overlay when you mouse over them, they display a different image.  If you export one button with highlight and one without, you can specifically set the hover image of the button to be the one with the highlight.  You specifically have options for selected, unselected and hover.

If you need more detail about how to do this specifically, I can put together some screenshots when I get to my editing workstation, but I seem to recall it being relatively easy to find in the properties of the button.